# Create conditionally a resource that contains a for_each argument

Tags: terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I'm trying to achieve the next behavior (pseudocode):

```
if var.zone_id is null:
  create no route53 record
else
  create many route53 records (using for_each)
```

This is my current configuration before applying any condition:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "cert-validation" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.main.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      //some attributes
    }
  }
  // more attributes
}
```

I tried to use this:

```
count = var.zone_id == null ? 0 : 1
```

Problem is that resource already has a `for_each` argument so my solution does not make much sense. I tried also something like this:

```
locals {
  dvos = var.zone_id == null ? [] : aws_acm_certificate.main.domain_validation_options
}
```

And iterate over `local.dvos`. But it does not work because a local cannot have a reference to a resource.

How could I solve this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`for` expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for) syntax includes an optional [`if` clause](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for#filtering-elements) that you can use to filter elements from the result. In your case you want to filter *all* of them when some condition is true, which you can achieve by writing an `if` clause that doesn't refer to either of the iterator variables:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "cert-validation" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.main.domain_validation_options : 
    dvo.domain_name => {
      //some attributes
    }
    if var.zone_id != null
  }
  // more attributes
}
```

If `var.zone_id` is `null` then this will filter out all of the elements, causing the value assigned to `for_each` to be an empty object. This would therefore declare zero instances of this resource in that case.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about that if clause 

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer. I can check the condition in the for loop itself:

```
...
for dvo in var.zone_id == null ? [] : aws_acm_certificate.main.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
...
```

If someone provides a better approach, of course it will be very welcome.